# How to create sticky bottom in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create sticky footer in swiftUI where other part of screen is scrollable but in footer there is one view with buttons and other element which should be fixed.

[image]

Thank You for help.

Comment: Do you have any examples of what you have tried so far? What could work is you add a scroll view and put the scrolling content inside that. Then below the scroll view (outside of the brackets) add a VStack with the data that you want to not move.

Comment: Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 9):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is stack vertically (VStack)

1. a Scrollview
2. another VStack (with the Toggle and the Button), aligned at the bottom :

```swift
VStack {
        ScrollView {...} // 1
        VStack {         // 2
             Toggle(...)
             Button(...)
        }
        .frame(alignment: .bottom)
}
```

To take your example :

```swift
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var checked: Bool = false
    let text = String(repeating: "blabla ", count: 20)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach((1...100), id: \.self) {_ in
                    Text(text)
                }
            }
            
            VStack {
                Toggle(isOn: $checked, label: {
                    Text("I have read...")
                })
                Button("Enter") {
                    // action
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding(.vertical)
                .background(Color.red)
            }
            .padding()
            .border(Color.black)
            .frame(alignment: .bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Your example]

Comment: explanation part at the beginning is pretty useful

Answer (score 4):

From **iOS 15.0+**, **macOS 12.0+**, **Mac Catalyst 15.0+**,**tvOS 15.0+**, **watchOS 8.0+** you can use [safeAreaInset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/safeareainset(edge:alignment:spacing:content:)-4s51l)

For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

        }
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
            footerView
        }
    }

    var footerView: some View {
        // your content
    }
}
```